# Display a progress screen for BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry

How to display a progress screen when BlackBerry application is fetching data from remote server ?

I want an progress screen without animated gif without any button. (OK or Cancel )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class ProgressDialog extends PopupScreen
    {
        public ProgressDialog(String waitString)
        {
            super(new VerticalFieldManager());
            add(new LabelField(waitString,Field.FIELD_HCENTER));//add a string which u want to show for progressing
        }
    }

ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog("Please Wait...");
//Add screen to UI
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(progress);


//Remove screen from UI
progress.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar("Waiting for location update....",50,1000);

progressBar.start(); // Start progress bar
progressBar.remove(); //remove progress bar
```

**ProgressBar Thread**

```
public class ProgressBar extends Thread {

    Thread thd;
    private int maximum, timeout;

    private boolean useful = true;

    private PopupScreen popup;

    private int iterations = 0;

    /**
     * Object constructor
     * 
     * @param title
     *           Text to display on popup area
     * @param maximum
     *           Range / width of the gauge field of progress bar
     * @param timeout
     *           Milliseconds to pause between updates to progress bar
     * @see GaugeField
     * @see Thread
     * @see PopupScreen
     */

    public ProgressBar(String title, int maximum, int timeout) {
        this.maximum = maximum;
        this.timeout = timeout;


        VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager();

        popup = new PopupScreen(manager);


        manager.add(new LabelField(title));

    }

    /**
     * run() method for starting thread
     */

    public void run() {

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);
            }
        });

        int iterations = 0;     

        while (useful) {
            System.out.println("I m  here in while runn  "+ useful);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeout);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if (++iterations > maximum)
            {
                iterations = 1;
                useful = false;
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run ()
                    {
                        _locationProvider.reset();
                        Dialog.alert("Location not found.");

                    }
                } );

            }

            //          gaugeField.setValue(iterations);            
        }

        if (popup.isDisplayed()) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(popup);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to shutdown the thread and remove the popup screen
     *  
     */

    public synchronized void remove() {
        useful = false;
    }

}
```